# How can I relate a Journey Exit to an Email Send in Automation Studio (Marketing Cloud)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

When a subscriber exits a personalized Journey, I would like to send an Email to a Data Extension containing several people. How can I achieve this?

Is it possible to relate a Journey Exit to an automation?

Answer (score 4):

You can add an Update Contact activity as the last step in the journey, which will modify a data extension column to include a specific value. Just create a column in your journey entry source DE called "journey_exit_date" and set the Update Contact activity to write the current datetime to that column.

Then you can run a query for automation studio to check for people who have that column filled and then separate them by date (if running this on a schedule) to only return those users you want to mail.